# Make query with association and search by custom model method rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this problem, i tried to get all Beauty Salons when the service has a promotion, but service has a custom method and return true or false, this is the structure of my code

```
class BeautySalon < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :services

end

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :beauty_salon
has_many :service_promotions
has_many :promotions, through: :service_promotions

def has_promotion?

 ## consult another tables and return true or false if found a promotion

end

end
```

iam tried to make the query like this

```
BeautySalon.all.includes(:services).select('services.*').select{|service| service.has_promotion?}
```

but rails return this error

NoMethodError (undefined method `has_promotion?' for #BeautySalon:0x0055a1119d1f40)

Any advice for this?

**UPDATE**

the method has_promotion do this

```
def has_promotion?
     if promotions.exists?
       if get_promotions(Date.today).exists?
         return true
       else
         return false
       end
     end
     return false
   end

def get_promotions(date)
     if promotions.exists?
       promotions.where('start_date <= ? and end_date >= ?',date,date)
     end
   end
```

and another tables are there

```
class Promotion < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :discount, presence: true
  validates :start_date, presence: true
  validates :end_date, presence: true

  has_many :service_promotions
  has_many :services, through: :service_promotions


end

class ServicePromotion < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :service_id, presence:true
  validates :promotion_id, presence:true

  belongs_to :service
  belongs_to :promotion
end
```

thanks for all the advises

Comment: How complicated is the `has_promotion?` method?  Can you paste the code for that?

Comment: Since you using your BeautySalon as starting point, query will always return  BeautySalon object(if using AR). Please post has_promotion? code

Comment: Hard to say how to model this unless you've done the work to define at least one kind of promotion and how the business logic will apply to it.  You can model a promotion and have many promotions for a beauty salon.  A promotion might have one service to which it applies, or  not.  List out the kinds of promotions you want to offer and the questions you will want to ask about them.  Try-out some possible relational models, and the kinds of queries you would write.

Comment: if you do model promotions in the data, then `has_promotion` could become a scope instead of a method.

Answer (score 0):

`BeautySalon.joins(:services).select { |beauty_salon| beauty_salon.services.any?(&:has_promotion?) }`

This is an option. You are now calling has_promotion? on the wrong object (e.g. beauty salon instead of service) and the error is raised because the instance method is defined in Service.rb.

It would be better in my opinion to add a database column has_promotion (boolean) to your services table.

`BeautySalon.joins(:services).where(has_promotion: true)`

If has_promotion? simply retrieves data from another associated model (other_association, with db boolean column promotion)  you can also do something like this:

`BeautySalon.joins(services: other_association).where(other_association: { promotion: true })`

Update:

`BeautySalon.joins(services: :promotions).where("promotions.start_date <= :date AND promotions.end_date >= :date", date: Date.current )`

This will return all beauty salons with running service promotions (today).

Comment: It would be better if this could be accomplished with a query (your second suggestion).  Whether there is a promotion might depend on a column, certainly, but more likely a relation; because there would be other data about the promotion beyond whether one exists or not.

Comment: It all depends on the content of the has_promotion method. If I know what it looks like I can make an efficient query for it. Now it is simply guessing.

Comment: thanks for the answer, try the first option but still not working, i thinking on the second option to but has_promotion? return true if service has a promotion in a range of time, i don't know how update the collumn every time

Comment: It would help if you say what errors you get. The code above is untested since I'm on my mobile, but it is usually easy to fix. I added an SQL option for retrieving beauty salons with running promotions.

Comment: Can you up vote and accept my answer if it solved your problem?